# Scala/Play framework parameter name with a dot in it

Tags: scala, playframework

Could be a silly question. I am developing a facebook realtime update notification service. For which Facebook first calls my GET service to verify caller. Facebook demands to have a parameter name with a dot in it. e.g. "hub.mode", and theere are 2 more with a dot in parameter name. I'll have provide such parameters available in my Play service. How do I create a parameter with a "dot" in it?

Secondly, can I have one single method serving both "GET" and "POST" requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the parameter you need without having to declare it in your route.
Example:

```
def myAction() = Action { request => // Don't forget this detail
    request.getQueryString("hub.mode") match {
      case Some(hubMode) => Ok(hubMode)
      case None => BadRequest
    }
}
```

And yes, you can have one single method that serves different HTTP methods.

Answer (score 0):

First: For dotted arguments you probably should make a use of `Nested values` like described [in the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaForms)

Second: yes, you can